# Maximum matching on a tree

Tags: graphs

How should I compute efficiently a matching of maximum size in a tree?

My thoughts so far: since from a path we can get a matching, then just finding the longest path in the tree should be enough to answer the question.

Am I wrong? another approach?

Answer (score 4):

You can do much better. Consider for example the tree in which the root has $N$ children, and each one has one child. The maximum matching has size $N$, but the longest path is only four edges long.

Here is a better algorithm. Choose a root arbitrarily. For each subtree, calculate the maximum matching within the subtree, as well the maximum matching within the subtree that doesn't touch the root of the subtree. You can think of it as a form of dynamic programming.

Many problems on trees can be solved efficiently using this kind of dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some pseudocode for [@Yuval Filmus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/86814/112107) answer:

```
// v must be the root of the tree on the first call.
// if the graph has no root, pick any vertex as the root
max_matching(v)
    max_matching(c) for children of v
    // cost of not including edges (v, c)
    score[v][false] = sum for children(v) c of max(score[c][false]; score[c][true])
    // max cost of including edge (v, c), the c vertex
    // without edges, and the remaining children (max of with/without edges)
    score[v][true] = max for children(v) c of (1 + score[c][false] + max for children(v) d of max(score[d][false]; score[d][true]) where c != d)
    if score[v][true] > score[v][false]
        add edge (v, c) to maximum-matching set where c is the matching vertex from score[v][true]
```

The maximum-matching set contains the edges once the function returns. If just the number of edges is required, it can be calculated from `max(score[v][false]; score[v][true])` where v is the root of the tree.